# Do case-insensitive ordering with django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Is it possible to do `case-insensitive` ordering by `first_name` with *Django-rest-framework*.

Here is the code:

```
import django_filter

class PersonFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('first_name_lower',)
        order_by = ('first_name_lower',)

class PersonViewSet(BaseModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = PersonFilter
```

Is there an easy way to do `case-insensitive` ordering with `django-filter`?

[Here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter) django-filter has docs for case-insensitive **search**, but nothing for **ordering**.

In the Django docs, the code is somewhat obtuse for this, which makes me wonder if it exists for `django-filter` or not.  Here's the Django docs code snippet on how to do it with the Django ORM:

```
>>> from django.db.models.functions import Lower
>>> MyModel.objects.order_by(Lower('myfield'))
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to subclass the `OrderingFilter` and use it as your `filter_backend` so that you can reuse the code.

```
from rest_framework.filters import OrderingFilter
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

class CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):
    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        ordering = self.get_ordering(request, queryset, view)

        if ordering is not None:
            if ordering.startswith('-'):
                queryset = queryset.order_by(Lower(ordering[1:])).reverse()
            else:
                queryset = queryset.order_by(Lower(ordering))
        return queryset


class PersonViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    filter_backends = (CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter,)
```

Comment: This solution will work, but only with a single `ordering` argument.

Answer (score 0):

The `case-insensitive` search can be done by overriding the `get_queryset` method on the `ModelViewSet` class.

It works for *descending* and *ascending* `case-insensitive` ordering.

```
# Example URL's
'/api/people/?ordering=-first_name'
'/api/people/?ordering=first_name'
```

Here's the code:

```
class PersonViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = self.queryset
        ordering = self.request.query_params.get('ordering', None)
        if ordering is not None:
            from django.db.models.functions import Lower
            if ordering.startswith('-'):
                queryset = queryset.order_by(Lower(ordering[1:])).reverse()
            else:
                queryset = queryset.order_by(Lower(ordering))
        return queryset
```

`from django.db.models.functions import Lower` only works for Ascending, so basically call `.reverse()` on it if you need to go Descending.

Comment: Just a quick note about your last sentence, you can actually do `Lower(ordering).asc() or Lower(ordering).desc()` which would allow to mix ascending and descending in combination with Lower on different fields.

Comment: this will fail in case the orderby field is a datetime field or any non string field

Comment: @JonathanLiuti thank's so much, that's the first I ever read about that possibility and solves a lot of my current issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `filter` function of `OrderingFilter`, and set the ordering params in `Lower`:

```
class CaseInsensitiveOrderingFilter(django_filters.OrderingFilter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        if value in django_filters.constants.EMPTY_VALUES:
            return qs

        ordering = [Lower(self.get_ordering_value(param)) for param in value]
        return qs.order_by(*ordering)
```

Answer (score -1):

use the ordering and ordering_fields arguments in your django-rest list view - http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#specifying-a-default-ordering

```
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,)
    ordering_fields = ('username', 'email')
    ordering = ('username',)
```

Comment: `ordering_fields`, etc... works for ordering, but it is *not case-insensitive*.  The Django ORM is `case-sensitive` by default, and the `ordering_fields` argument above uses the default Django ORM functionality for `model.objects.order_by`.